# Regex | CASE WHEN THEN ELSE "keep same value"

Tags: regex, case, looker-studio, re2

I am trying to group certain `source/medium` dimensions in Google Data Studio and leave the original value for the rest; for example:

```
CASE
  WHEN (source/medium = “lnkd.IN|linkedin.*”) THEN “Linkedin”
  ELSE “”
END
```

Can the `ELSE` be blank to keep the same original value?

Comment: Could you elaborate by providing a publicly editable Google Data Studio Report (additionally, a Google Sheet if it's the data set) of the scenario (using sample data that shows 1) Input values (~10 rows) 2) Expected output 3) An attempt at solving the issue)? It would help users visualise the issue and test out suggestions on a specific use case with objective right / wrong answers. Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it would be difficult to pinpoint a suggestion and the issue, e.g. Data Set, Data Source, Report, Fields, Chart

Answer (score 0):

Put the column that you're updating in the `ELSE` clause, so it will assign the original value back to the column.

```
SET columnname = CASE WHEN (`source/medium` RLIKE 'lnkd\\.in|linkedin\\.') THEN 'Linkedin' ELSE columnname END
```

Comment: Note that in Google Data Studio, `SET` as well as `RLIKE` are currently not implemented, thus adding the respective commands / functions, which would result in error messages such as: `Syntax error: Unexpected "SET"` or `Syntax error: Expected ")" but got...`

Answer (score 0):

Your else clause should just be the column that you're testing on if you want it to remain unchanged. For example if your column name is "source/medium", it would be like this:

```
CASE WHEN (source/medium = “lnkd.in|linkedin.*”) THEN “Linkedin” ELSE source/medium END
```

Comment: Note that using the calculated field in the answer would (currently) result in an error that states: `Syntax error: Illegal input character. Check that your formula does not contain smart quotes.`